# How do unlock other quest areas?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've adventured in the desert, the cave, the forest, the castle, the lighthouse & the sea.  But judging by a lot of questions I don't begin to even understand, there must be other areas. How do I get there?

Comment: The trick is to hover the cursor all over the map because there are spots that you can go which are not obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Besides what you've already listed, you should still have The Hole, The Desert Fortress (of which there are three rooms), Hell, and The Developer to battle. A list of all map locations can be found [here.](http://images.jayisgames.com/elle_candybox2_02.png)

As for unlocking the above areas, The Hole should be available once you've beaten the Forest, the Desert Fortress is unlocked by finding the key within a chest inside The Hole, Hell is reached by selecting 'Challenge' while talking to the Dragon, and the Developer is reached by picking 'Fame' while talking to to the Dragon.